# Rebuilding a BST into AVL

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, time-complexity, avl-tree

How will you rebuild a given BST into AVL which contains exactly the same keys?
The algorithm running time should be O(n) and its allowed to use O(n) additional space. Any ideas?
The whole pseudo-code is not necessary, any idea or suggestion would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to turn a potentially unbalanced binary tree into a balanced (AVL) tree? Have you done any research on this at all?

Comment: Find each unbalanced node and balance it. Ya that is the simplest way. Start from leaves and then moved up.

Answer (score 2):

1. Extract all keys to sorted array *(O(n) space)* with suitable traversal method *(O(n) time)*
2. Build perfectly balanced tree from sorted array *(O(n) time)* (simultaneously filling AVL balance factors for all nodes)

I 've omitted the details for your own research